# What is "Guards killed on horseback" for guild challenges?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

One of the Guild Challenges for the Mercenary's Guild in Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood states:

> - 25 Guards killed while on horseback

Does this mean I need to kill 25 guards while *I* am on a horse, or kill 25 guards while *they* are on a horse?

I tried testing both but the counter seemed to increment way less than the number of each type that I killed, so I'm not sure if I'm missing some special requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Assassin's Creed Wiki](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Guild_Challenges),

> "On horseback" means that the guards must spawn on horseback, not Ezio.

and [this walkthrough](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/996092-assassins-creed-brotherhood/faqs/61389),

> You are not on the horse, killing guards. You have to
>   kill the guards that ride horses. Some guards start out on foot, but will jump
>   on a horse if you attack them. They do not count. The guard must spawn on the
>   horse.

it appears that Ezio is allowed to be on foot, and must kill 25 guards who spawn on horseback.

Comment: Ah, I think it might have been the ones jumping onto horseback not counting that screwed up my testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My testing showed that both ezio and the guard had to be on horseback, but I could kill either by crossbow or by jumping to the other horse with hidden blade. When there were two guards on horseback I only got credit for one, so I think you have to be anonymous as well.

Answer (score 0):

Get out of the city, get on a horse, select the hidden blade, ride along the roads, look for horsemen on those roads, get near them, focus on them, press the assassinate button when the option shows up. Ezio will jump on the other horse and kill the horseman. Works every time.

Ubisoft should have made it more clear. Took me a lot of testing to get to this.